# What will display this command?

Tags: linux

As a result of issuing the command `ls d??[G-L]?`, what will display?

I tried in every way and I can not display anything on the screen.

Comment: The output you get will entirely depend on the names of the files in your current directory. Do you have any files that match that name pattern? If not, make one and try again: `echo >dxxGx`

Answer (score 2):

The name of any file in the current directory that is five letters long, starts with a 'd', and has a G, H, I, J, K or L as its second-to-last letter.

If you don't have any of those, it will likely display nothing (or an error).

Comment: The second to last can actually also be J or K.